# How to override Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme for edittext

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create a style for EditText (MyEditText), which inherits from base theme and added extra property settings.

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_back_indicator</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#dbffb1</item>
</style>
```

When applied MyEditText style to EditText control, existing styles (from theme) seems to be overridden (like line under EditText vanished). Same thing happens when background is changed for EditText in the layout.

I am using targetSdkVersion 23.
I like to know what is the proper method to override a single property from default theme.

Here is the code for EditText in layout (as asked by @3amoura):

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:id="@+id/et_description"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
    android:lines="10"
    android:hint="Describe your complaint in details"
    android:gravity="top"
    style="@style/MyEditText" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

If you are only trying to add a color of the Line drawn -> `setBackgroundTint`

If you want to change both the background color and the line color, then custom layer-list or selector will be the only option. A sample layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#dbffb1" /> <!-- background color-->
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:left="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/colorAccent" />  <!-- color of stroke -->
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: setBackgroundTint did not have any effect. My Devise is running kit kat 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

The style of MyEditText should inherit from *Widget.AppCompat.EditText* instead of *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar* such that it will be

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
<item name="android:background">#dbffb1</item>
```

Then you use the style in the EditText xml

Comment: I have tried this, but all the theme features are vanished leaving only the background colour from MyEditText.

Comment: Can you post the xml of the Edit Text in your question

Comment: I have added the xml for EditText